# Making a linear automaton with Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR)

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, cryptography, coding-theory

i am a software developer new to the site i am currently learning about lfsr , everyday i solve a question which is given to me ,but today i am lost, i can not solve this one , so i am asking for your help, for hints, or for any thoughts.

TASK:
Make a linear automaton with the help of LFSR   of this recurrent sequence:

$s_{n+4} = s_{n+3}+s_{n+1}+s_{n} $

Thank you.

Comment: This is a site about mathematics.

Comment: yes but it is highly related to mathematics.

Comment: Everything is highly related to mathematics. Your question belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the $s_i$ are bits (= elements of the field $\Bbb{F}_2$) then problems like this do occur in coding theory courses (and in the applications). If they are something else (real or complex numbers or...) then it is probably not about coding theory. Anyway (assuming that they are, indeed, bits), if you have ever seen a diagram of an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) this is basically about drawing taps in the correct places. If not, then I don't know what the point is.

Comment: can you help me please with that i am completely lost.